# Login with Amazon

Tags: android, authentication, sha256, api-key

I want to implement login functionality with an amazon seller central account. I was following the steps online for setup with amazon login and in one of the steps I have to register my android app in order to receive an api key. While registering the account, it asks for a signature value (32 hexadecimal pair value SHA-256) which i am not able to find out. The problem is my android application hasn't been released, so I am unsure if a build application also has a signature value or not? 
Can someone please let me know how to get the signature for an unreleased android app?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to sign your app. You can do it easily in Android Studio. Check "Sign an APK" section from the link
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

You don't need to release your app for getting the signature.